# How to prove/disprove this algorithm time complexity is O(M+N) amortized?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

The following [problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-division/) has 2 described solution. Let N be the number of input equations and M be the number of queries:

- One uses union find and is O((M+N)log*(N))
- One uses DFS and is O(M*N)

However it seems to me that answering all queries at the end with DFS will have an O(M+N) runtime. The below code passed all tests and was accepted by the OJ.

**General outline**

- Build a graph. Each equation (a/b) = x creates two weighted edges from a to b with weight x, and from b to a with weight 1/x.
- I run DFS over all variables and record the connected components. For each letter, I maintain in which connected components it is via component_map.
- Each var in the component has a value V = captain/var, where captain was the first variable inserted
- Then for each query I can answer when both belongs to the same component without need of backtraking since (captain/var1* var2/captain = var2/var1)

The key differences between my DFS solution and theirs are:

- I do not need to backtrack due to last bullet above
- I answer all queries at once at the end

My reasoning is that every single operation I do is amortized O(1),  basically with hash maps and vectors. I run DFS inside a loop with N iteration, but the sum complexity of all my DFS calls will be O(M+N) as every node is only visited once.

I hence believe this solution to be O(M+N).

**Question**: Am I correct? Can you prove the time complexity of this algorithm whatever it is?

```
class Solution {
public:
        typedef unordered_map<string,double> component;     // var --> captain/var
        typedef unordered_map<string,component> components; // captain --> component , each component identified by its captain.
        typedef unordered_map<string,string> component_map; // var --> captain, to what component this var belongs?
        typedef unordered_map<string, vector<pair<string,double>>> adjacency_list;
    
    void DFS(const string& node, component& compo, adjacency_list& adj, double value, unordered_set<string>& visited,component_map& m, const string& captain)
    {
        for(auto p: adj[node])
        {
            if(compo.find(p.first) == compo.end())
            {
                visited.insert(p.first);
                m.insert({p.first,captain}); // this letter belongs to this "captain component"
                compo.insert({p.first,value*p.second}); // insert L,V
                DFS(p.first,compo,adj,value*p.second,visited,m,captain);   
            }
        }   
    }
    
    vector<double> calcEquation(vector<vector<string>>& equations, vector<double>& values, vector<vector<string>>& queries)
    {
        adjacency_list adj;
        for(int i=0;i<equations.size();++i)
        {
            string a = equations[i][0];
            string b = equations[i][1];
            double v = values[i];
            
            auto it = adj.find(a);
            if( it == adj.end())
            {
                adj.insert({a,{}});
                it = adj.find(a);
            }
            it->second.push_back({b,v});
            
            it = adj.find(b);
            if( it == adj.end())
            {
                adj.insert({b,{}});
                it = adj.find(b);
            }
            it->second.push_back({a,1/v});
        }
        
        components cps;
        unordered_set<string> visited;
        component_map m;
        
        for(int i=0;i<equations.size();++i)
        {
            string a = equations[i][0];
            if(visited.find(a)==visited.end())
            {
                auto it = cps.insert({a,{}}).first;
                DFS(a,it->second,adj,1,visited,m,a);
            }
            
            string b = equations[i][1];
            if(visited.find(b)==visited.end())
            {
                auto it = cps.insert({b,{}}).first;
                DFS(b,it->second,adj,1,visited,m,a);
            }
        }
        
        vector<double> res;
        for(auto& q:queries)
        {
            auto it0 = m.find(q[0]);
            auto it1 = m.find(q[1]);
            
            if(it0 != m.end() && it1 != m.end() && it0->second == it1->second)
            {
                auto& captain = it0->second;
                auto& cp = cps[captain];
                res.push_back(cp[q[1]]/cp[q[0]]);
            }
            else
            {
                res.push_back(-1.0);
            }
        }
        
        return res;
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, would my sketchy reasoning to describe complexity be accepted in interview? In Academia definitely not... but in interview?

Comment: In the past, I've written algorithms research papers and graded algorithms homework. Now I give interviews from time to time. (Not speaking for my employer.) This is more than fine for an interview. It might be a little too informal for algorithms homework, but it really just depends on the rubric. I can't imagine docking too many points if any. For a research paper, yes, you would probably write up the proof of correctness more formally but also gloss over the running time since it's DFS with obviously constant-time overhead in various places.

Comment: I'm surprised that the judge passed this solution, since the problem statement does not promise that there are no 0 values.

Comment: @MattTimmermans but it did: `0.0 < values[i] <= 20.0`

Comment: Well, the only funny part is that if you got a query ['x','x'] and x is not present in any equation, you need to answer -1... though since no value are 0 it could be answered anyway.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I guess it's fine, then...  and nobody else thought of reducing adjacent edges?  Anyway, I do a lot of tech interviews, and would accept the reasoning in this answer without difficulty.  I might ask a follow-up about how to get the most accurate answer possible.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I do not really have the choice of the product order for the doubles. 

Just using BFS with a normal queue, would decrease the number of multiplication to minimum, as path would be shorter.

At best I could do would be using a BFS with a priority Q, trying to always have the smallest product because precision is higher near 0? but then my time complexity would increase by log N.

The most accurate answer would require to run BFS or pBFS between all pairs directly not with the captain to be sure to have the shortest/lowest product, but then complexity would be much higher.